# Shorebird flutter code push cannot be installed in my Linux ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: flutter, code-push, shorebird

I have followed [this article](https://medium.com/@vovaklh20012/code-push-for-flutter-update-your-app-without-new-release-using-shorebird-d3575ba0a2c0) and when I run the command:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shorebirdtech/install/main/install.sh -sSf | bash
```

It cloning the project and fails to install and here is the errors in the image
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpbkv.png)
Any one can help with this issue?

I have already tried to run the same command with sudo but the same issue appears